# TEntity Type or Namespace Could Not Be Found

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was hoping someone could give me a hand here.
In the official docs, it states that TEntity should live within the `System.Data.Entity` as can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460(v=vs.113).aspx

However, even with `using System.Data.Entity;`, I'm still getting the `The type or namespace TEntity could not be found`. Did I do something wrong here? I feel like I made a dumb error :(

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace Assignment1.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, string authenticationType)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        DbSet<TEntity> Smartphones { get; set; }

        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I'm using Entity Framework 6.0+

Comment: Wait a second... my design model goes where `TEntity` does, right?

Comment: `TEntity` is a generalized class name. you should place the model class name there.